# How to write LINQ expression for Elastic search match and fuzzy query(NEST)

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, lambda, nest

Hi have a query in which i have to match using fuzzy operation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "answer": {
        "query": "conevrt o",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i try to write this using Lambda expressions style im getting an error saying cannot convert int to NEST.fuzziness.

here is my take on lambda expression.

```
 match = drFuzzy.Text; //im getting text from the asp:dropdown(hardcoded 0,0.5,1,2)
  int fuzz = Int32.Parse(match); // converting this to integer


var searchResponse = client.Search<StudResponse>(s => s
                    .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Answer)
                    .Query(key1)
                    .Fuzziness(fuzz) //throwing an error here. cannot convert from int to Nest.Fuzziness
                   )
                )
            );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass fuzinness parameter you will have to use `Fuzziness` class and `EditDistance` method. NEST documentation has a really nice example of [match query usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/match-usage.html), have a look.

This is how you can use `Fuzziness.EditDistance(..)` code in your use case.

```
client.Search<StudResponse>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Answer)
            .Query(key1)
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(fuzz))
        )
    ));
```

Hope it helps.